# Manage multiple roles with FosUserBundle symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am new to symfony,i am using FosUserBundle for user management now i want to do role management (managing role with separate table) with FosUserBundle and need to give access to user as per role assigned to him/her. Please suggest some good solution to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use user groups for set needed role for users. And check it with isGranted('ROLE') method in controller or in twig templates

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation for the configuration of security.yml :

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Then after specifying your ROLES there in the hierarchy you can start giving access to specific roles in the access_control part of the security.yml configuration.

For some reasons you will want to check in the twig or in the controller there are also some function which allow you to check if the user is granted this or that Role with :

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('YOUR_CUSTOM_ROLE');
```

or twig :

```
{%if is_granted('YOUR_CUSTOM_ROLE')%} /* show some custom data */ {%endif%}
```

You can add or remove roles from Users also using :

```
   $user->removeRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
   $user->addRole('YOUR_CUSTOM_ROLE'); 
   $em->persist($user);
   $em->flush();
```

This is mostly what you will need the roles for in general, access_control configuration, Twig checks, Controller Checks and Add/Remove Roles.

Comment: Thanks for your ans..yes i can manage access control by  security.yml configuration but here i want  to manage access control(dynamically) with database. Is there any way with symfony that i can use to manage access with database table ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is an ACL for database but there is Symfony's ACE access control entity combined with ACL you can allow a ROLE to edit a specific entity http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html